# How to send variable string in SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, string, variables

I need to send a variable string as the message. I am using SKTPSMTPMesaage to send a food order from my app to the bakery. Help? Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,

                            @"string goes here",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *plainPart = 
      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"text/plain",
kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey, 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"string goes here%@",yourVaraibleName],   
kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",
kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
```

Notice the stringWithFormat call. You can entirely replace with your variable string  by removing the text 'string goes here' ( ignore the quotes) .